# Unable to send email using mailgun in node.js

Tags: node.js, mailgun

Unable to send email using mailgun in node.js and not showing any error

```
import express from 'express'
import mailgun from 'mailgun-js'
({apiKey: 'process.env.APIKEY',  domain: process.env.DOMAIN})
```

function on button Click from react

```
const data = { from: 'process.env.EMAIL', to: req.body.email,
               subject: 'Welcome!',html: '<p>Welcome!</p><p>You are very special!</p>'}
```

mailgun function

```
 mailgun.messages().send(data, (error, body) => {
                if (error)console.error(error)
                elseconsole.log('done')                     
             })
```

Answer (score 1):

The
`message().send()` is asynchronous method. In react I would suggest

```js
<button onclick={async () => {
 await mailgun.messages()
    .send(data, (error, body) => {
        if (error)console.error(error)
        else console.log('done')                     
     })
}>
  Activate Lasers
</button>
```

However, be aware of publishing your private API keys from mailgun. It could be abuse. Let's call some back-end service that handles all the stuff.